# How to copy specific folder to another folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I got real problem and until now I couldn't solve it. I'm using Visual Studio C# Windows form application.
I just want to copy "2019"  folders in " Source" folder with given name 20190401, 20190402, and 20190403. In "Source" folder have random folders such as "2018", "2017" and more. The result that I want is after I click a button then it automatically only "2019" folders in "source" folder will copy to "target" folder, and only 3 text files in 2019 folder will be copy then.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        string FROM_DIR = "C:/Users/5004117928/Desktop/Source";
        string TO_DIR = "C:/Users/5004117928/Desktop/Target/";
        string filename = "t";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            DirectoryInfo diCopyForm = new DirectoryInfo(FROM_DIR);
            FileInfo[] fiDiskfiles = diCopyForm.GetFiles();

             foreach (FileInfo newfile in fiDiskfiles.Take(3))
             {
                 try
                 {
                     if (newfile.Name.StartsWith(filename))
                     {
                         File.Copy(newfile.FullName, TO_DIR + newfile.Name);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output after I click a button, all 2019 folders will copy to 
"target" folder with 3 text files inside every 2019 folder that have been copy.

Comment: bit confusing as there is no code for copying folder?....only files are gonna be copied to target folder....

Comment: Do you want to copy the folders with all their contents or somehow choose 3 text files in each folder that should be copied with each folder?

Comment: One Question about coding (Visual Studio C# WindowsformApplication)
There have 2 folder: (Source and Target) and I build 1 button "Copy"
In "Source" folder have random folders such as "20190401", "20190402", "20190403", "20180401", "20170401" and "20160401". Every of these folders have [10] .txt files.

What is the coding if I only want to copy all "201904**" folders with [3] .txt files inside it to "Target" folder? Which mean I only copy all folders StartWith "201904**" with [3] text files from "Source" folder to "target" folder after I click a button.

Answer (score 0):

Let's implement the routine step by step:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  // "I just want to copy "2019" folders in " Source" 
  string FROM_DIR = "C:/Users/5004117928/Desktop/Source";

  // "with given name 20190401, 20190402, and 20190403"
  HashSet<string> acceptedFiles = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "20190401", "20190402", "20190403"
  };

  // "I want is after I click a button then it automatically only "2019" folders"
  // Here we enumerate all files to copy:
  //   - they are from FROM_DIR, 2019 subfolder
  //   - they are in acceptedFiles ("20190401", "20190402", "20190403")
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(FROM_DIR, "2019"), "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file => acceptedFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)))
    .ToArray();

  // will copy to "target" folder 
  string TO_DIR = "C:/Users/5004117928/Desktop/Target";

  // Copy:
  foreach (var sourceFile in files) {
    // for given sourceFile we change its folder
    string targetFile = Path.Combine(TO_DIR, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));

    File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile);
  }
```

**Edit:** If you have many a directory to choose from, let's enumerate tham and add `Where`:

```
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(FROM_DIR, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(dir => new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name.StartsWith("2019"))
    .SelectMany(dir => Directory
       .EnumerateFiles(dir, "*")
       .Where(file => acceptedFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))))
    .ToArray();

  ...
```

Comment: One more Question about coding (Visual Studio C# WindowsformApplication) There have 2 folder: (Source and Target) and I build 1 button "Copy" In "Source" folder have random folders such as "20190401", "20190402", "20190403", "20180401", "20170401" and "20160401". Every of these folders have [10] .txt files. What is the coding if I only want to copy all "201904**" folders with [3] .txt files inside it to "Target" folder? Which mean I only copy all folders StartWith "201904**" with [3] text files from "Source" folder to "target" folder after I click a button.